# Time Synch Architecture in Windows Domain Environment

Tags: windows-server-2008, time

I just read the following article --

"In a domain, time synchronization takes place when Windows Time Service turns on during system startup and periodically while the system is running."

( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx )

From the above article i get to know that the first sync it take as soon as i start my system, but after that in how many minutes or second or in how many periodic interval my windows client ( Window XP, window7 or window server 2008 member ) synch with my Domain controller (PDC emulator )???

Do you have any idea,  and how should i verify my synch time interval?

My Domain Controller is Window server 2008 R2 Standard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the following registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpClient\SpecialPollInterval`

This value is the interval in seconds.  However, according to the Windows time Service blog, unless you manually set the `SpecialPollInterval` it will use a "dynamic interval that is determined by synchronization algorithms built into Windows Time Service".

Your article also specifies this and says that by default `SpecialPollInterval` is set to 604800 for workgroup computers, and 3600 for domain computers.  So once a week for workgroup, and once an hour for domain computers.

As far as checking last sync time, check the event log for source Windows Time events, or you can use command "w32tm /query /status" and view "Last successful Sync Time"

MSDN source: [Configuring the Time Service: NTP Server and SpecialPollInterval`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/w32time/archive/2008/02/26/configuring-the-time-service-ntpserver-and-specialpollinterval.aspx)

Comment: Hi Mikes, Thank you so much for your Answer. I really appreciate it. I have check in my Event Viewer. My Laptop is in Domain still there is no log for time Synch. Can you please help me why? there is no log. i have check for the source W32time and the command which you have given is not working in window XP.. Thanks & Regards,